# Ruby 2.3.15 error: Malformed version number string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working on upgrading an old Rails app running Rails 2.3.2 on Ubuntu to the latest Rails 2.3.15. The app originally had a vendored version of rails in `vendor/rails` but I have removed that, installed the `rails 2.3.15` gem, and changed the version number in `config/environment.rb` to:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.15' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Upon restarting the app, I get this error message in the mongrel log (which prevents the app from starting):

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/version.rb:53:in `initialize': Malformed version number string  (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:105:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:105:in `version_for_dir'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:47:in `refresh!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:45:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:45:in `refresh!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path'
     ... 17 levels...
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

What do I need to do to get past this error?

Comment: Could you perhaps print the `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` so that we can see which version number is being used?

Comment: When/where do you want me to do that?

Comment: Because of the source of the error (`rubygems/version.rb` - that is, the `version` module of `rubygems`), I'm guessing `rubygems` is saying either that its own version number is malformed, or that a gem it's trying to load has a malformed version number. Hmm.

Comment: Also note the two spaces at the end of the error message. Most versions of this error on Google seem to be of the form `Malformed version number string SOMETHING`. Sounds like it's trying to report that it's seeing a blank version number string where it's expecting it to be, well, non-blank.

Comment: Could it be that, since you've removed the vendored copy of Rails, it's still trying to read the vendored copy but not finding it? And therefore reporting a blank version number? Just a guess :/

Comment: I don't think so because I also ran `rake rails:unfreeze` which didn't do anything except remove the `vendor/rails` directory

Comment: `add_frozen_gem_path` is in the error message. Does it have something to do with frozen gems in `config/environment.rb`? Check out the `config.gem` lines?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question...

Rails was expecting that only directories would be in `vendor/gems`, but there was an `init.rb` file in there which was trying to add the gems to the load path (which is already handled by Rails).

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer this particular question but I had a similar error message after upgrading my Ruby on Rails version to `7.1.1` and to solve it, I just ran:

```rb
gem install bundler
```

The error occurred because my Gem version was out of date